# Angular 2 CLI is compiling but browser not reflecting changes made in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angular, webstorm

I have just started learning Angular 2 through a tutorial.

I made a new project using `ng new firstapp`. Whenever I make changes to `app.component.ts` and save the file, the angular-cli always compiles successfully, displaying `webpack: Compiled successfully`.

However, sometimes it immediately reflects the changes in browser whilst most of the times it doesn't show any change. After I searched for the issue, someone suggested to try disabling the cache using Chrome developer tools but it didn't help. I am a beginner.

I am using WebStorm as my IDE. However when I made changes using SublimeText, the browser reflected the changes immediately. I guess it has got something to do with WebStorm. I'd like to carry on using WebStorm, as I love its features.

Comment: Did you run `ng serve?`

Comment: @itamar Yes obviously!

Comment: If there is no issue when swapping IDE's, then I suggest that you re-work this question to reflect this new finding - to target people who will give you better answers. (title change).

Comment: What is your `@ngtools/webpack` version in your project `npm show @ngtools/webpack version` ?

Comment: @Kuncevic it is `1.2.8`

Comment: you could try to do a `shift + ctrl + r` or `shift + cmd + r` to force refresh the cache in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using webpack-dev-server, it’s [recommended](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#working-with-editors-ides-supporting-safe-write) to disable the IDE **Safe write** feature (`Use "safe writes" (save changes to a temporary file first)`, `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings` ) , otherwise, the app won’t be updated on-time on changes. This issue is fixed in Webpack 2

Comment: Thanks a ton! Fixed my issue.